# Delete all domain cookies without knowing the path

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I accidentally set some cookies that I shouldn't have. For example, my cookie is called "lang", and my mistake was not setting the domain nor the path of the cookie. So, the browser created the cookie with the defaults, which meant that users who visited the "products" page of my website ended up with a cookie like:

```
Name        Value        Domain        Path
lang        en           example.com   /products/
```

When in reality, the cookie should've been:

```
Name        Value        Domain        Path
lang        en           example.com   /
```

The bad code was there for a little while, which means that the path of the cookie happens to be whatever page the user was visiting.

**My question is, is it possible for me to delete all the cookies under the example.com domain without knowing the paths?**

I've tried it in both JS and PHP, but without passing the path of the cookie, the browser refuses to delete it. Given how long the bad code was live, there are possibly thousands of paths. The reason there's so many paths is because most users come from Google, so they land directly on a page like `example.com/products/a-product`, which means that the path of the cookie will be `/products/a-product`

Thank you

Comment: Are we talking about a site where you don't have access to the code or a site you have full access to the code ?

Comment: My site, where I have full access to the code.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a possible solution in PHP... We just unset the cookies by changing the expiration time. Please report to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#refsect1-function.setcookie-examples).

## Delete ALL cookies

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    // We get the server cookies
    $server_cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    // We set the expiration time
    $expiration_time = time() - 3600;
    // And the default _path
    $default_path = '/';

    foreach ($server_cookies as $cookie) {
        // We explode given cookie in order to simply get the cookie name
        $all_parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        // We get the cookie name
        $name = trim($all_parts[0]);

        // We set the expiration time & empty the value
        setcookie($name, '', $expiration_time);

        // We set the path, empty the value and set the expiration time
        setcookie($name, '', $expiration_time, $default_path);
    }
}
```

## Delete specific cookie when we know its name & informations

```
// We set the cookie name we wand to delete
$name = 'lang'; // According to OP
// We set the path of the cookie
$path = '/products/';
// We set the domain of the cookie
$domain = 'exemple.com';
// We set the expiration time
$expiration_time = time() - 3600;

// We set the expiration time & empty the value
setcookie($name, '', $expiration_time);
// We set the path, empty the value and set the expiration time
setcookie($name, '', $expiration_time, $path, $domain);
```